# undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass with stripe connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use the [omniauth-stripe-connect](https://github.com/isaacsanders/omniauth-stripe-connect) gem. I have followed every step in the recommended tutorial (linked in the documentation of the gem) [here](https://www.munocreative.com/blog/stripe-connect-rails/). Whenever I click the button I created to send a user to Stripe to get their stripe info and update the database, I get an error. I am clicking the button while logged in as a user, and I have all the fields in my database.

```
undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass
```

Specifically, this line:

```
provider: request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
```

initializers/devise.rb

```
 config.omniauth :stripe_connect,
    ENV['STRIPE_CLIENT_ID'],
    ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'],
    :scope => 'read_write',
    :stripe_landing => 'register'
```

I have these in my .env file.

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

omniauth_callback_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def stripe_connect
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes({
      provider: request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
      uid: request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid,
      access_code: request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token,
      publishable_key: request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.stripe_publishable_key
    })
      # anything else you need to do in response..
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Stripe") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.stripe_connect_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    # If we do get failures we should probably handle them more explicitly than just rerouting to root. To review in the future with colo
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

and the button in the view:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/blue-on-light.png'), user_stripe_connect_omniauth_callback_path(:stripe_connect) %>
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "access_code"
    t.string   "publishable_key"
  end
```

Comment: What is the value in `request.env`?

Comment: Try to debug if you are getting anything in `request.env`

Comment: I honestly don't know how to do that. I was assuming it was using the values in my .env file.

Comment: Add `byebug` or `pry` in your Gemfile and the add `byebug` or `binding.pry` at the first line in this method `def stripe_connect`

Comment: when that method is called on your development server the debugger will stop it there and you can check the values of the variables

Comment: It stopped and put an arrow on the line `@user = current_user`.

Comment: Now you can check the values of `params`, `request.env` or any variables or methods accessible from that method/action

Comment: `display request.env` brought up a whole page of stuff. `display params` resulted in `2: params = <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"omniauth_callbacks", "action"=>"stripe_connect", "format"=>"stripe_connect"} permitted: false>`

Comment: What do you see when you do `request.env['omniauth.auth']` in action `stripe_connect`?

Comment: It returns nil. So that must mean there is a problem that it's not seeing the stuff in the devise initializer?